# How to look up a fragment by its location/coordinates

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have a view with a lot of different fragments in it. I want a method that takes in pixel coordinates and returns the Fragment at that location (if any). Does such a method exist? If not, how would I go about creating one?

Comment: Why u creating a lot of fragments in one view? I mean isn't that a list/recylerview job to such scenario?